# Is it possible to use Jasmine's toHaveBeenCalledWith matcher with a regular expression?

Tags: jasmine

I have reviewed Jasmine's documentation of the [toHaveBeenCalledWith](http://pivotal.github.com/jasmine/jsdoc/symbols/jasmine.Matchers.html#toHaveBeenCalledWith) matcher in order to understand whether it's possible to pass in a regular expression for an argument, if that argument is expected to be a string. Unfortunately, this is unsupported functionality. There's also an [issue open on github](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/issues/243) requesting this functionality.

I've dug a bit into the codebase, and I see how it might be possible to implement this inside the [existing matcher](https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/Matchers.js#L235). I think it would be more appropriate to implement it as a separate matcher though, so that the abstraction is captured individually.

In the meantime, what might be a good workaround?

Answer (score 96, accepted):

After doing some digging, I've discovered that [Jasmine spy](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies) objects have a `calls` property, which in turn has a [mostRecent()](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-28) function. This function also has a child property `args`, which returns an array of call arguments.

Thus, one may use the following sequence to perform a regexp match on call arguments, when one wants to check that the string arguments match a specific regular expression:

```
var mySpy = jasmine.createSpy('foo');
mySpy("bar", "baz");
expect(mySpy.calls.mostRecent().args[0]).toMatch(/bar/);
expect(mySpy.calls.mostRecent().args[1]).toMatch(/baz/);
```

Pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 43):

As of Jasmine 2.2, you can use [`jasmine.stringMatching`](https://jasmine.github.io/2.2/introduction.html#section-String_Matching_with_%3Ccode%3Ejasmine.stringMatching%3C/code%3E):

```js
var mySpy = jasmine.createSpy('foo');
mySpy('bar', 'baz');
expect(mySpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  jasmine.stringMatching(/bar/),
  jasmine.stringMatching(/baz/)
);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted solution if you are using the most recent Jasmine. I received errors when I tried using `.argsForCall` and `.args`

Comment: And this is why my default answer view is "Active" and not "Votes."

Answer (score 24):

In Jasmine 2.0 the [signature changed a bit](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-28). Here it would be:

```
var mySpy = jasmine.createSpy('foo');
mySpy("bar", "baz");
expect(mySpy.calls.mostRecent().args[0]).toMatch(/bar/);
expect(mySpy.calls.mostRecent().args[1]).toMatch(/baz/);
```

And the [Documentation for Jasmine 1.3](http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/introduction.html#section-Spies) has moved.

Answer (score 13):

Alternatively, if you are spying on a method on an object:

```
spyOn(obj, 'method');
obj.method('bar', 'baz');
expect(obj.method.argsForCall[0][0]).toMatch(/bar/);
expect(obj.method.argsForCall[0][1]).toMatch(/baz/);
```

Comment: In Jasmine 2.0, the syntax would be `obj.method.calls.argsFor(index)`, still an Array.

Comment: If you're trying this in angular (2+), typescript doesn't seem to like it so you might have to do use bracket notation `obj.method['calls']['argsFor'](index)` to get around type checking

Answer (score 8):

Sometimes it is more readable to write it this way:

```
spyOn(obj, 'method').and.callFake(function(arg1, arg2) {
    expect(arg1).toMatch(/bar/);
    expect(arg2).toMatch(/baz/);
});
obj.method('bar', 'baz');
expect(obj.method).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

It give more clear visibility of method arguments (instead of using array)

Answer (score 7):

As jammon mentioned, the Jasmine 2.0 signature has changed. If you are spying on the method of an object in Jasmine 2.0, Nick's solution should be changed to use something like -

```
spyOn(obj, 'method');
obj.method('bar', 'baz');
expect(obj.method.calls.mostRecent().args[0]).toMatch(/bar/);
expect(obj.method.calls.mostRecent().args[1]).toMatch(/baz/);
```