# How to test if jQuery load() is being called with Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a javascript function `deleteSomething()`, within which the load() function in jQuery is called.

```
function deleteSomething(a, b){
    deleteIt(a, b, function(success){
        if(success){
            $("#table").load(...);        
        }
    })
}
```

Now I want to test `deleteSomething()` with Jasmine to see if load() is being called. But got `Error: Expected a spy, but got Function`

```
describe("deleteSomething", function() {
    beforeEach(function () {
        ...
    });
    it("should call load() when deleteIt returns true", function() {
        spyOn($('#table'), 'load'));

        deleteIt.and.callFake(function(a, b, callback){
            callback(true);
        });
        deleteSomething(a, b);

        expect($('#table').load).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

I'm new to Jasmine, how should I do this?

Comment: How did you spy on `load`? share the code?

Comment: @Thaadikkaaran I updated the code. Thanks.

Comment: @HMR's answer should work for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to spy on jQuery [prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes), it is available here: `$.fn`.

So your code should look something like this:

```
describe("deleteSomething", function() {
  it("Should call load", function() {
      //$.fn is where the load function is defined
      //  $("...") returns a new jQuery.fn instance that has load function
      //  from jQuery.fn.prototype
      spyOn($.fn, 'load');
      $("#anything").load();
      expect($.fn.load).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Some more information about the difference of object own members and prototype members (inherited) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941).

Comment: How do you test if load() is being called on the correct element?

Comment: @JennySaqiurila `expect($.fn.load.calls.argsFor(0)[0]).toBe("#table");` https://stackoverflow.com/a/21873859/1641941 (first comment)

Comment: Thx for the information! I managed to make it work like this: `expect($.fn.load.calls.mostRecent().object[0]).toBe(document.getElementById("table"));`